# Difference between DisplayDocumentActionTaskPane and Visible property

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-interop, vba

I am working on excel vsto solution.

Not able to understand exact difference between below properties.

```
1. Application.DisplayDocumentActionTaskPane 
2. Application.CommandBars["Task Pane"].Visible = false;
3. Workbook.ActionsPane.Visible
```

Is there any difference between this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7we49he1.aspx

Comment: Thanks. According to this document I have concluded that for excel vsto project DisplayDocumentActionTaskPane and Application.CommnandBars["Task Pane"].visible is the same. Am I right?